# Expected mean question

Tags: probability, statistics

A junior actuary created a simple model for the amount of damage that will be caused by an insured in the coming year.

Let $D$ denote the amount of damage. She found the expected damage to be $E(D)=600.$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
D&0&1000&50000&10000\\
\hline
Pr(D)&0.82&0.10&x&y\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

(a) Find the missing probability.

This question seems to be simple, but I just can't figure it out. $600= 100+5000x+10000y.$

I don't know what the next step will be. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to provide the table in the question in a well readable form, it's easier for people to answer. 

You have an additional condition on $x$ and $y$ since all probabilities need to sum up to $1$. Then you have two equations, one you stated and one from this additional condition, and you have two unknowns $x$ and $y$. You can then solve the system for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: sorry. I am new to this so I am getting used to it. I will try to present in a better form in the future. I see that I have to equate two equations to find the missing probability Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

It is known that the expectation is $600$, so one equation we have is

$$ 1000(0.10) + 5000x + 10000y = 600 $$

However, the values of the PMF must sum to $1$ so the other equation is

$$ x + y = 0.08$$

Two equations, two unknowns. Go.